# how can i put the value of "value" field in a form where input type is checkbox from database?

Tags: php, mysql, html

i tried alot in order to fetch values from database and put it in check-box array but failed.Please help!!

***img[] comes out to be empty all the time like no value is going into it when ever i call that part using $_POST(['img'])!!***
here's my code:

```
   echo " <h2>Select image to delete: <h2>";
   $s = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM image WHERE u_id = '$u_id'");
   $num = mysql_num_rows($s);

   if($s)
   { 
      ?>
   <form name="f1" method="post" action=""> 
      <?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($s))
    { 
      ?>      
    <input type="checkbox" name="img[]" value="<?php $row['path'] ;?>" />
    <img width="100" src="<?php echo $row['path']." ";?>">
    <?php                 
    }
    ?>
       <br />
       <br />
       <input type="submit" name= "subDel" value = "Delete" />
       </form>
     <?php

    }
```

Comment: You forgot to echo in the input field.

Comment: corrected--> but i still cant delete multiple images the way it should work!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this? :)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="img[]" value="<?php $row['path'] ;?>" />
```

=>

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="img[]" value="<?php ECHO $row['path'] ;?>" />
```

Comment: but i still cant delete multiple images?? :(

Comment: Just read second answer below carefully. Shortly - you should get an array with valuese of all checked checkboxes. You can do something like this: `for($_POST['img'] as $img_path) { \\delete your image here}`

Comment: And do not forget to check if there is something in it (if nothing checked $_POST['img'] will return null and for loop will throw a Notice)

Comment: tht's the issue..img[] is just picking up one value. if you select multiple it wont do anything!!

Comment: See this link [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php#87650). If you are using $_POST['img[]'] you should get nothign. Instead of that you should use $_POST['img'] which provide an access to an array of selected values. PHP simply turns all name="img[]" to $_POST['img']

Answer (score 0):

Retrive post Data in PHP by using $_POST['variableName'] - no brackets, case DOES matter

In your case, $_POST['img'] is of type *array*. There is NO value for unchecked items. If nothing checked, your post variable is empty or even undefined (didn't test it yet).

Access your values by

```
if (array_key_exists($index, $_POST['img']) == true) {
    // $index is checked
    $doSomething = $_POST['img'][$index];
}
```